# chartjs-plugin-annotations not displayed in primeNG chart

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, primeng

Trying to draw a horizontal line on a PrimeNg chart doesn't seem to work using the chartjs-plugin-annotation. I'd rather not install another charting library unless I have to.

```
 <p-chart #decisionPlot type="scatter" [data]="decisionPlotData" [options]="decisionPlotOptions"  [plugins]="decisionPlotPlugins"  [height]="defaultHeight" (onDataSelect)="onPlotClick($event)">
  </p-chart>
```

In ngOnInit() is this:

```
const namedChartAnnotation = ChartAnnotation;
namedChartAnnotation['id'] = 'annotation';
Chart.pluginService.register( namedChartAnnotation);
this.decisionPlotOptions = this.plotService.getAnnotationsOptions();
```

and in the plotService is this:

```
getAnnotationsOptions() {
return {
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
  annotation: {
    annotations: [{
      // drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
      id: 'hline',
      type: 'line',
      mode: 'horizontal',
      scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
      value: .5,
      borderColor: 'red',
      borderWidth: 10
      }]
    },
plugins: [{
  annotation: {
  annotations: [{
    // drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
    id: 'hline',
    type: 'line',
    mode: 'horizontal',
    scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
    value: .5,
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 10
    }]
  }
}]
```

};
  }

I've also tried assigning the plugins directly using the [plugins] attribute on the component, but no love.
Is this a lost cause?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the scaleID from 'y-axis-0' to

```
scaleID: 'y-axis-1'
```

resolved my issue. It took, oh so so long to squash that lil ol typeo bug.